# BroadcastReceiver for Incoming SMS is not working in Android 4.4 and above

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my project I am having BroadcastReceiver for listening to incomming SMS.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.project.cdacReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This code is working fine but if I do **Kill/Force Close** the application in Android 4.4.2 then the application is not receiving Broadcast for Incoming SMS. I have tried in Android 5.0 also, am getting the same problem.

is anything am doing wrong or from android 4.4 and above are they have done any changes?

Comment: if you force close your app you no longer receive any broadcast from 3.1

Comment: Is this for all type of broadcast or only Incoming sms receiver?